# To find correspondents in data-frames for calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

Two data frames like below and I want to calculate the correlation coefficient.

It works fine when both columns are completed with actual values. But when they are not, it takes zero as value when calculating the correlation coefficient.

For example, Addison’s and Caden’s weights are 0. Jack and Noah don’t have Weights. I want to exclude them for calculation.

(In the tries, it seems only consider the same lengths, i.e. Jack and Noah are automatically excluded – is it?)

How can I include only the people with non-zero values for calculation?

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

Weight = {'Name': ["Abigail","Addison","Aiden","Amelia","Aria","Ava","Caden","Charlotte","Chloe","Elijah"], 
'Weight': [10, 0, 12, 20, 25, 10, 0, 18, 16, 13]}

df_wt = pd.DataFrame(Weight)

Score = {'Name': ["Abigail","Addison","Aiden","Amelia","Aria","Ava","Caden","Charlotte","Chloe","Elijah", "Jack", "Noah"], 
'Score': [360, 476, 345, 601, 604, 313, 539, 531, 507, 473, 450, 470]}

df_sc = pd.DataFrame(Score)

print df_wt.Weight.corr(df_sc.Score)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masking and taking non-zero values and common index:

```
df_wt.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
df_sc.set_index('Name', inplace=True)

mask = df_wt['Weight'].ne(0)
common_index = df_wt.loc[mask, :].index
df_wt.loc[common_index, 'Weight'].corr(df_sc.loc[common_index, 'Score'])

0.923425144491911
```

If both dataframes contains zeros then:

```
mask1 = df_wt['Weight'].ne(0)
mask2 = df_sc['Score'].ne(0)
common_index = df_wt.loc[mask1, :].index.intersection(df_sc.loc[mask2, :].index)
df_wt.loc[common_index, 'Weight'].corr(df_sc.loc[common_index, 'Score'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for add new column, remove `0` rows by[`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last apply your solution in same DataFrame:

```
df_wt['Score'] = df_wt['Name'].map(df_sc.set_index('Name')['Score'])

df_wt = df_wt[df_wt['Weight'].ne(0)]
print (df_wt)
        Name  Weight  Score
0    Abigail      10    360
2      Aiden      12    345
3     Amelia      20    601
4       Aria      25    604
5        Ava      10    313
7  Charlotte      18    531
8      Chloe      16    507
9     Elijah      13    473

print (df_wt.Weight.corr(df_wt.Score))
0.923425144491911
```